# ComboBox Selected Item in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, wpf-controls

How do you set the combobox selected item in xaml?
I tried something doing like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProject"
    ItemsSource="{Binding  Project}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Project,Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The above code does not work.  I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemsSource` property should be a Collection, i.e. `Projects` or `ProjectList`, I guess... Also, you only need to set the `DisplayMemberPath` and the `SelectedValue`:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbProject" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}"
           DisplayMemberPath="Name"
           SelectedValue="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Update: based on the info in the comments the code becomes:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProjectStatus"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectStatuses}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValuePath="ID"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ProjectStatus.ID}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectStatus}" />
```

The `DataContext` has a `ProjectStatus` property of type `ProjectStatus` and a `ProjectStatuses` property of type `ObservableCollection<ProjectStatus>`.

Comment: I tried it, But still it is not showing the selected item in the combobox.

Comment: It worked for me when I tried, how do you set the selected item? Can you post the code?

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="cmbProjectStatus" ItemsSource="{Binding  ProjectStatuses}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ProjectStatus,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=StatusId,Mode=OneWay}>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` for the combobox?
This worked for me.